# Move price of upsell block

Tags: magento-enterprise

Just wondering if there's a way for me to move the price between the image and the product title in upsell block?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes There is solution for that

**Note:: You have to change in theme Folder if you don't have upsell.phtml file then just copy form base folder as this path and do the changes `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\list\upsell.phtml`**

**Step 1:** Open this file you check `line no 40`.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true, '-upsell') ?>
```

**Step 2:** Below this line you can see

```
<h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_link->getName()) ?></a></h3>
```

**Step 3:** Copy and paste `price` line above `<h3>` block.

**Step 4:** Refresh the cache and run your site.

Let me know if any comments.

Comment: Thanks Keyul! I'm already on the upsell.phtml I just didn't saw the price code :) Thanks a lot

Comment: you welcome :).